Azure Redis ReadOnly user Connection string C#
We are using current version of Azure Redis. Our client is C# StackExchange.Redis.
I added a readonly user.
Where / how to specify this user in my c# connection string ?

Below connection string does not have any option to include readonly user userid/ password



Where / how to specify this user in my c# connection string ?

To access user you need to add that particular user in Azure Redis Users. So, it takes that user as user id,  password will be generated automatically in the connection string itself. As you can see in the below image, the particular user is added in the Redis Users.

Below is the c# example which connects successfully by using Connection string.
using System;
using StackExchange.Redis;

namespace RedisReadOnlyExample
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
        {
            string connectionString = "******";
            return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(connectionString);
        });

        public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection => lazyConnection.Value;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var db = Connection.GetDatabase();

                string key = "sampleKey";
                string value = "sampleValue";

                Console.WriteLine($"Value for '{key}': {value}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}

Output:
Value for 'sampleKey': sampleValue

For more info refer to this doc.
